# Save post action is called twice

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post

I've seen this posted several times with no perfect answer:

I have an action hook for save_post on a CPT. I've tried everything I could find but it always gets called twice:

Here's my code:

```
function mySavePostCustomFunc( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
 
     // If this is just a revision, or if it is an autosave

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) )  {
        return;
    }


     if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
    }

    // don't run the echo if the function is called for saving revision.
    if ( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) {
        return;
    }


    if (!$update) { // if new object
        return;
    }


     if (get_post_type($post_id) != 'my_post_type') {
        return;
     }
 
    // this gets called twice
    error_log("post save function was called");


     $curDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    

     // I've tried commenting this out also
     update_post_meta( $post_id, 'update_time_meta_field', $curDateTime);


}

add_action( 'save_post_my_post_type', 'mySavePostCustomFunc', 10, 3 );
```

Thanks

Comment: Which editor are you using? Keep in mind that some plugin and theme authors don't know how to save post meta in the block editor and instead resorted to making an AJAX call that updates the post, they may be the cause, but there's not enough information to diagnose this. How are you testing this code? And how do you know how many times it runs?

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm the plugin author and this is the only plugin installed on the site. The block editor is what's being used. I know it's being called twice because in my version I have an error_log("post save function being called") inside the function.

Comment: and have you confirmed that the messages both come from the same request? How are you differentiating between the function being called twice, versus a REST API endpoint being hit in 2 separate requests? You can do this by using a counter, if the counter increments then it's the same request. The issue I mentioned above still applies even if you aren't the one making the extra requests. If you can test while verifying this happens with the default theme and no other plugins?

Comment: Also, where in the function did you put the `error_log` call? Do you have any `wp_insert_post` or `wp_update_post` calls in your code? If the function is called multiple times have you confirmed if it's called the same way with the same parameters for the same post? Or are they different?

Comment: @TomJNowell I've updated my OP with the error_log() included. The counter doesn't increment so I'm assuming it comes from separate requests, but I don't have any other actions hooking onto it that I know of (I've tried commenting out update_post_meta()). 

I'm using Underscores and no other plugins installed. Is there any way to find out where there other request is coming from?

Comment: You can look in the browser dev tools network panel to see what requests are being made. Although, what you're trying to save in the hook is also the value `post_modified` will have

Comment: @TomJNowell You're the man -- this is what I get for trying to do a quick local fix for and not configuring https on my local server for the domain. It was being called twice -- once over http and another time over https: Did a quick test --     $referrer = wp_get_referer();

    if (strpos($referrer, 'http:') !== false) {
     error_log("not the right referrer, aborting");
     return;
    }

I know this post_modified field, but I had other updates going on that I didn't want to fill my OP with. Thanks again. Will watch your wordpress.tv vids now

Comment: are you doing HTTPS redirects in WordPress? I'd recommend switching to an Nginx/Apache based redirect instead

Comment: @TomJNowell Using WP Engine for production which does Nginx based redirects -- but locally I'm running "Local".

Answer (score 1):

I noticed there was a 302 redirect in my network tab while saving. Save_post was being triggered twice, once from

Inside my call, I simply included:

```
$referrer = wp_get_referer();

if (strpos($referrer, 'http:') !== false) {
    error_log("not the right referrer, aborting");
    return;
}
```

Issue solved.